# Using Mosquitto with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I'm trying to write a simple MQTT client command line application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mosquittopp.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    mosquitto_lib_version(&a, &b, &c);
}
```

Whenever I call *mosquitto_lib_version* I get the following error (the same for any other mosquitto function).
*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mosquitto_lib_version referenced in function _main*.

I installed Mosquitto (32-bit) and tested the broker using command line tools.
I ensured that the relevant .h, .cpp and .lib files are present in --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel.
I specified the following properties for the project:

- VC++ Directories | Include Directories --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel
- VC++ Directories | External Include Directories --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel
- VC++ Directories | Library Directories --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel
- VC++ Directories | Source Directories --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel
- Linker | Additional Library Directories --> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel
- Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies --> mosquittopp.lib

I tried running VS in normal and admin mode.

I'm building for Win32, in Debug Mode.

All the above failing, I added NuGet package for Mosquitto 1.0.2 to no effect as well.

**-------------UPDATE--------------**

It was a mistake on my part: I only added mosquittopp.lib to Additional Dependencies of the linker. I should've added mosquitto.lib as well.
Obviously all the DLLs from Mosquitto installation directory need to be in the same directory as my exe (or visible to VS in another way).

Comment: If you have a solution, please add it as a proper answer not as an edit to the question. You can then accept the answer and it will show higher search results for others